# how do I print the contents of a <cite>?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-crawler

Im trying to pull the links with python that google provides and idk why it doesnt work.
the error  :

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'text'
```

my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

input = input('what do you want to *scrape* ?\n>')

driver = webdriver.Opera()
driver.get('https://google.com')    
print(driver.title)
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input')
search.send_keys(input)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN )
headers = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h3')
cites = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('cite')

for cite in cites :
    print(cite.text)

time.sleep(5)
print('done')

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code and it worked fine after providing the path of the Operadriver executable

driver = webdriver.Opera(executable_path=r"C:\operadriver.exe)

Answer (score 0):

Try to cite.getAtrribuet("innerHTML")
Or cite.getAttribute ("outterHTML")
Or excuter.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML",cite) or replace inner to outter